# React Native pod install fails [nanopb]

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, project, react-native-cli

pod install fails with this error, anyone know what to do?

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "nanopb":
  In Podfile:
    EXFirebaseAnalytics (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-analytics/ios`) was resolved to 2.4.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 6.14.0) was resolved to 6.14.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.1.7) was resolved to 6.1.7, which depends on
          nanopb (= 0.3.9011)

    RNFBCrashlytics (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics`) was resolved to 8.4.2, which depends on
      Firebase/Crashlytics (~> 6.30.0) was resolved to 6.30.0, which depends on
        FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 4.4.0) was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
          nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
```

Comment: I'd go with `rm Podfile.lock` `pod deintegrate` `pod install` and if still now working, `pod repo update`

Comment: Those two libraries (EXFirebaseAnalytics and RNFBCrashlytics) conflict - they rely on different versions of `nanopb`. One of those libraries has to go (if still broken after the `pod repo update`).

Comment: well, since @SamuliHakoniemi have mentioned, I've checked but there's no **Podfile.lock**, only **Podfile**, so I followed what Adam said and remove EXFirebaseAnalytics for the meantime then ran all commands given by SamuliHakoniemi except the first one. It continued but then encountered another issue with **BMSCore** and failed, here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826116/react-native-pod-install-fails-bmscore, hope you guys can help me with it too, thanks